# Fortify scan on maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, fortify

I have configured Fortify plugin in Eclipse I am to scan Java projects from it but not the Maven projects.  I have looked to the other answers already but did not worked.

`C:\Program Files\HP_Fortify\HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.11\plugins\maven` in this path I have some ZIP files which I am not able to access as it need admin access and 1 read me file.

`C:\Program Files\HP_Fortify\HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.11\Samples\advanced\maven-plugin` at this location I have only 1 read me file which says *"The SCA Maven Plugin was moved to /plugins/maven"*.

What all changes I need to do and if any thing needs to be downloaded in Eclipse then how to do that?

Fortify tool 16.11

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I completely understand your problem/question.

But if you are looking for the Eclipse Plugins of Fortify, the will be exposed into your SCA installation directory, after you install sourceanalyzer.

In the mentioned ZIP file you will only find the Fortify Remediation Plugin, which is good to read the report, but it is missing the whole collaborative process.

Hope this helps.